# Detect type of calculation via vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a spreadsheet set to manual calculation for time saving (it takes a long time to calculate).

I'd like to offer some way of advising the user whether a calculate needs to be performed or not to get the whole workbook up to date. I've not thought it through fully yet, but in my head I need to be able to distinguish the calculates that a user performs.

I.e. I need a worksheet_calculate event to be able to recognise if the user has done a shift-f9 or a ctrl-shift-f9 and to be able to alter it's behaviour according to that.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: What if the user chnages the calculation from the menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `onkey` :

```
Sub TrackKeys()
   Application.OnKey "+{F9}", "Recalculate" 
End Sub

'in your sub you can call the calculations mode to be changed.
Sub Recalculate()
   Sheet1(1).Range("A2:E5").Calculate
End Sub
```

Found the link: Try this for a better explanation :)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919127

Comment: Yep - this will work well. I also noticed that a shift-f9 hits the Worksheet_Calculate event first then the Workbook_SheetCalculate event  whilst a ctrl-xhift-alt-f9 does it the otherway around. I imagine you could do something with that but your method if cleaner.

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks mate, but I wish I had noted down yours :) because you were wrapping up the calculation mode.

Comment: @chrisSpaceman glad you can make this to work the way you want :)

Comment: @chrisSpaceman you should post your comment above as an answer